# C# - Is there a way to create cookie from "set-cookie" header in HttpClient and pass it as a cookie to a new request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

Let's say I created a new HttpClient and send a post request:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1/api", content);
```

Now one of the response header contains "set-cookie" header.

I need to create a cookie using the mentioned header and pass it to further requests done by the HttpClient object.

I tried the following code, but it's not working.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var cookie = new Cookie("CookieName", "cookie_value");
var result = await client.GetAsync("/test",cookie);
```

My main question, is how can I read the cookie for HttpClient response and add send further request to the server using the cookie.
Just to be clear. I don't have any issue reading the header or saving cookies, as I'm able to do it with other cookies created manually as in the example above

Comment: You need to set the actual name and value from the server. If you are doing that in your actual code - and not just passing strings as you have shown in your question - please **edit** your question to show the real code.

Comment: @stuartd , yes the question was how do I get those values and pass it as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the way to do so is by using cookie container:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1/api", content);
var setCookieValue= response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

var baseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/api/...");
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("CookieName", setCookieValue));
    var result = await client.GetAsync("/test", content);
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```